# Spark DataFrame column name case sensitivity in sparkSQL and Spark Submit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When i am querying dataframes on spark-shell(1.6 version) ,the column names are case insensitive .
On Spark-Shell

```
 val a = sqlContext.read.parquet("<my-location>")
   a.filter($"name" <=> "andrew").count()
   a.filter($"NamE" <=> "andrew").count()
```

Both the above results gives me the right count.
But when i build this in a jar and run via "spark-submit",below code fails saying NamE does not exist,since underlying parquet data was saved with column as "name"

Fails:

```
a.filter($"NamE" <=> "andrew").count()
```

Pass:

```
a.filter($"name" <=> "andrew").count()
```

Am i missing something here?is there a way i can make it case-insensitive.
I know i can use a select before filtering and make all columns as lowercase alias ,but wanted to know why is it behaving differently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a bit tricky here: the plain answer is because you think you're using the same `SQLContext` in both cases when, actually, you're not. In spark-shell, a SQLContext is created for you, but it's actually a `HiveContext`:

`scala> sqlContext.getClass
res3: Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext] = class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext`

and in your spark-submit, you probably use a simple `SQLContext`. According to @LostInOverflow's link: `Hive is case insensitive, while Parquet is not`, so my guess is the following: by using a `HiveContext` you're probably using some code associated to Hive to download your Parquet data. Hive being case insensitive, it works fine. With a simple `SQLContext`, it doesn't, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: Using HiveContext instead of SQLContext resolved this.Also if you want to use SQLContext,then we can use sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.caseSensitive","false"),so that it becomes case insensitive

Comment: Didn't know for the ```sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.caseSensitive","false")```, nice.

Answer (score 7):

[The part you're missing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hiveparquet-schema-reconciliation):

> ... is case insensitive, while Parquet is not

You can try:

```
val b = df.toDF(df.columns.map(_.toLowerCase): _*)
b.filter(...)
```

Comment: Then why is it working when i query same parquet data via spark-shell?

Comment: I have no clue.

Answer (score 5):

Try to control the case sensitivity with sqlContext explicitly. 
Turn off case sensitivity using below statement and check if it helps.

`sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false")`